# Correct use of "evolving"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs

Can someone give me the words to describe what is wrong with the use of 'evolving' in this sentence? I know how to make it sound better, but I don't know how to explain to my writer what is wrong.

> A new frontier of data collection is evolving how we interact with our world...'

In this context "A new frontier of data collection" is marketing-speak describing the birth of a data collection industry based around the use of innovative digital tools/techniques that didn't exist a few years ago. So while that part of the sentence also looks odd, it makes sense in the broader context in which it is being used.

My main question is - is the use of the word "evolving" here ungrammatical, or is it just unusual?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just unusual. It doesn't sound wrong to me as a native speaker and the dictionary lists the following definition:

> Develop gradually.
>   [...]
>   [*with object*] ‘each school must evolve its own way of working’
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evolve)

More precisely, the Oxford English Dictionary (which is a different dictionary from the one quoted above) has the following definition:

> *transitive*. To produce or give rise to (a condition, circumstance, process, etc.) as a natural consequence. Also *intransitive*: to arise.

It quotes the following which is pretty close in form to your quote:

> Timurid architecture evolved that vibrant vocabulary of colour and form.
>   <sub>*Story Islamic Architecture*, 1999</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this transitive use of evolve is quite right, that one thing can evolve another, rather a species is seen as evolving its attributes.

We can say

> The spoonbill has evolved a highly specialised beak for feeding ...

We don't say

> The muddy estuary conditions evolved the spoonbill

I'm not really sure that frontiers are capable of doing anything, but if we accept this marketing term then we might say

> A new frontier of data collection stimulates evolution in how we interact with the world.